# Handle a file-ending non-printable ASCII character in Python

Tags: python, ascii

Steps:

- I have some DBF files.
- I use DBF Converter to export them to SQL.
- I then use Python to do some basic string cleanup and import into SQL Server.

The problem:

Somehow, I don't know how, one row in the DBF file converts out the ASCII non-printable character [SUB](http://www.december.com/html/spec/ascii.html). Python treats this as the end of the file, and so it freaks out at me that I haven't properly terminated the string.

How would I, on a Windows machine, replace all ASCII symbols with anything else, without Python flipping out?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in binary mode yet?

Comment: Python doesn't treat \x1a as an end-of-file marker. You must be using some sort of dbf parser and that's the code that has the problem. Can you give us more details on what you are using/

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - text mode changes line endings but leaves other characters alone. \x1a should not be affected.

Comment: This is an old vestige of 1970's CP/M. Files in CP/M didn't have actual lengths, just number of blocks, so text files had to be explicitly terminated with \x1A. MSDOS had file lengths, but dragged along the old EOF character anyway because some old code depended on it. They also used it as a way to indicate EOF at the keyboard. Now in Windows in 2015, we have libraries that treat \x1A as enf-of-file. Yet another reason to never use Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace non-printable symbols using the re module, but that may not solve the problem you have here. DBF is a binary file format and there are lots of non-ascii characters in it.

```
import re
ascii_sym_re = re.compile(r'[\x00-\x09\x0b-\x1f\x7f-\xff]', re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
print ascii_sym_re.sub('.', 'hello\x1athere')
with open('somefile','rb') as fp_in, open('somefile-scrubbed', 'wb') as fp_out:
    fp_out.write(ascii_sym_re.sub('.', fp_in.read())
```

Comment: @XtinaS - oops, my bad. I've fixed the regex to match the proper range and fixed the sub's to replace the funky chars with '.'.

Comment: After that fix, and adding a parenthesis and changing fp to fp_in, it totally worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @XtinaS - LOL, some of the code was correct, anyway.

Comment: Close enough for government work! :) Plus, good exercise for me in troubleshooting code.